# Get sources of a snapshot dependency on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, jakarta-ee

Something bother me a lot... 
On a big project with many dependencies, some of them are set as SNAPSHOT in Maven2.

The matter is that it seems i can't get the sources through Eclipse without loading the project or fixing the dependency to the last release. 
For debugging, it's really annoying me...

**EDIT**

This is what i get in eclipse maven console:

```
26/08/10 11:31:46 CEST: Downloading http://repo-maven/archiva/repository/snapshots/com/blabla/1.1-SNAPSHOT/blabla-1.1-20100824.213711-80-javadoc.jar
26/08/10 11:31:47 CEST: Could not download sources for com.blabla:blabla:1.1-20100824.213711-80
```

On archiva i can see the deployed stuff i want to retrieve in eclipse...

```
Repository   snapshots
Group ID  com.blabla
Artifact ID  blabla
Version  1.1-20100824.213711-80
Packaging  jar
Parent  com.blabla bla 1.1-SNAPSHOT (View)
Other Versions  1.1-20100824.213535-79
```

I can download sources of this artifact with my browser but not within Eclipse... Any idea?

Comment: Weird. Can you run `mvn dependency:sources` on the command line to see if you can reproduce. And if you can, try with `-X -e` and see if you can get useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The matter is that it seems I can't get the sources through Eclipse without loading the project or fixing the dependency to the last release. For debugging, it's really annoying me...

Well, these modules are probably not publishing source JARs as part of the "regular" build process (i.e. outside the release). If these modules are under your control (which is my understanding), configuring the [Maven Source Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) to produce source JARs for them and deploying them in your corporate repo should solve the problem. From the [Usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/usage.html) page:

> ### Installing the sources along with your artifact
>
> There are two ways to do this. You can
>   either bind this plugin to a phase or
>   you can add it to a profile. The goals
>   source:jar-no-fork and
>   source:test-jar-no-fork are preferred
>   for binding the goal to the build
>   lifecycle.
>
> #### Installing the sources using a phase binding
>
> Here is how you would configure the
>   plugin in your pom.xml to run
>   automatically during the verify phase:
>
> ```
> <project>
>   ...
>   <build>
>     <plugins>
>       <plugin>
>         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>         <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
>         <version>2.1.2</version>
>         <executions>
>           <execution>
>             <id>attach-sources</id>
>             <phase>verify</phase>
>             <goals>
>               <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
>             </goals>
>           </execution>
>         </executions>
>       </plugin>
>     </plugins>
>   </build>
>   ...
> </project>
> ```
>
> We are using the verify phase here
>   because it is the phase that comes
>   before the install phase, thus making
>   sure that the sources jar has been
>   created before the install takes
>   place.
>
> #### Installing the sources using a profile
>
> If you want to install a jar of your
>   sources along with your artifact
>   during the release process, you can
>   add this to your pom.xml file:
>
> ```
> <project>
>   ...
>   <profiles>
>     <profile>
>       <id>release</id>
>       <build>
>         <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>2.1.2</version>
>             <executions>
>               <execution>
>                 <id>attach-sources</id>
>                 <goals>
>                   <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
>                 </goals>
>               </execution>
>             </executions>
>           </plugin>
>         </plugins>
>       </build>
>     </profile>
>   </profiles>
>   ...
> </project>
> ```

Using a profile would probably be a good idea so that building source JARs will only be done by the build running at the CI server level but not on developer machines.

Comment: Thanks it's not under my control but will have some words with the architects ;)